# Handling graceful shutdown in Springboot and Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

How to handle graceful shutdown in Kafka consumers using Springboot application?
We are using @KafkaListener, offset at consumer side. Is there any way to handle graceful shutdown in Kafka?

Provided graceful configuration in application.properties file (server.shutdown = graceful). It is working for normal rest calls, but this graceful scenario is needed in Kafka consumer.